# Way to calculate the execution time difference of two python scripts using sage

Tags: python, sage

I have two python scripts `Des.py` and `DDes.py` and I want to calculate their execution time difference using a sage script.

Comment: Not quite sure what Sage has to do with this...

Comment: Is there no way to do this in sage?

Comment: As far as I can tell (I've never used Sage though), it's really just a set of python libraries, so you're just asking how to do it in Python.

Comment: You are right but I have these 2 des implementations and I want to compare their robustness and performance.. and I think sage is the way to go.

Comment: Any reason you can't just run `time python Des.py` and `time python DDes.py` and do a difference between their respective sums of user and system CPU time?

Comment: Sorry, if I'm mistaken, but I want those commands to run inside a script, not to have to manually execute them in bash

Comment: Ok. Just follow Harm's answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see why you would want to do this with sage. Just use the time module:

```
import time

Start_Time = time.time()
#execute script
Execution_Time = time.time() - Start_Time
```

Execution_Time gives the total execution time in seconds.

Regards,
Harm